# I am not able to send my object body into two input fields in angular

Tags: java, angular, mongodb, typescript, spring-boot

**Here Is My Backend Model**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ItemType {
    @Id
    private String itemTypeId;
    private String typeName;
    @Indexed
    private ItemType parentItemType;
}
```

**Here is my backend service**

```
public ItemType createItemType(ItemType itemType) throws ResourceAlreadyExistException, ResourceDoesNotExistException {
    Optional<ItemType> itemTypeByTypeName = itemTypeRepository.findItemTypeByTypeName(itemType.getTypeName());
    if (itemTypeByTypeName.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResourceAlreadyExistException("Type Name Is Already Exist", "Please Enter A Valid Type Name");
    }
    if (itemType.getParentItemType() != null) {
        Optional<ItemType> parentItemType = itemTypeRepository.findItemTypeByTypeName(itemType.getParentItemType().getTypeName());
        if (!parentItemType.isPresent()) {
            throw new ResourceDoesNotExistException("Parent Type Name Does not Exist", "enter a valid parent");
        }
        itemType.setParentItemType(parentItemType.get());
    }
    return itemTypeRepository.save(itemType);
}
```

**Here is my backend controller**

```
@PostMapping("save")
    public ResponseEntity<ItemType> saveItemType(@RequestBody ItemType itemType) {
        try {
            ItemType savedItemType = itemTypeService.createItemType(itemType);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(savedItemType, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

**Here is my frontend model  ItemType.ts**

```
export class ItemType {
    public itemTypeId: string;
    public typeName: string;
    public parentItemType: ItemType;


    constructor(itemType?) {
        itemType = itemType || {};
        this.itemTypeId = itemType.itemTypeId || FuseUtils.generateGUID();
        this.typeName = itemType.typeName || null;
        this.parentItemType = itemType.parentItemType || null;
    }
}
```

**Here is my forntend service (Create Method)**

```
createItemType(itemType: ItemType): Observable<any> {
      return this._apiService.post(this._create_item_type, itemType, this._httpHeaders);
    }
```

**Here is my front end Component ts file**

```
public createForm(): FormGroup {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
            typeName: [this.itemType.typeName, Validators.required],
            parentItemType: [this.itemType.parentItemType]
        });
    }

    public saveForm(itemType: ItemType, formDirective: FormGroupDirective): void {
        this.createItemType(itemType, formDirective);
    }

private createItemType(itemType: ItemType, formDirective: FormGroupDirective): void {
        this.itemTypeService.createItemType(itemType).map((data) => {
            Utils.showAlert('success', 'Success', 'New Item type has been added!');
            formDirective.resetForm();
        }).subscribe(
            () => {
                // console.log(' NO ERROR FOUND ');
            },
            (error) => {
                Utils.showAlert('error', 'Oops...', error.headers.get('messageDescription'));

                // console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }, () => {
                // console.log(' FINAL RESULT ');
            });
    }
```

**Here is my frontend html file**

```
<mat-tab-group>

                <mat-tab label="Types">
                    <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" #formDirective="ngForm" class="product w-100-p" fxLayout="column"
                          fxFlex (ngSubmit)="saveForm(form.value, formDirective)">
                        <div class="tab-content p-24" fusePerfectScrollbar fxLayout="column">
                            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" fxFlex="48">
                                    <mat-label>Type Name</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput placeholder="Type Name"
                                           name="typeName"
                                           formControlName="typeName" required>
                                </mat-form-field>

                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" fxFlex="48">
                                    <mat-label>Parent Type Name</mat-label>
                                    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Parent Type Name"
                                           name="Parent Type Name"
                                           formControlName="parentItemType" [matAutocomplete]="itemType">
                                    <mat-autocomplete #itemType="matAutocomplete">
                                        <mat-option>

                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-autocomplete>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="mat-accent" mat-raised-button>
                                SAVE
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </form>

                </mat-tab>

            </mat-tab-group>
```

**I want to send this type of JSON file**

```
{
    "typeName" : "Chair",
    "parentItemType": {
        "typeName": "Furniture"
    }
}
```

Initially parenTypeName will be null. After create parent type under this parent type i am trying to send 'Chair' under the parent type 'Furniture' but failed. So how can i send this JSON?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: **From backend i got this error**
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 36] (through reference chain: bd.edu.seu.erp.prs.model.ItemType["parentItemType"])]

** From Frontend **
In console 
POST http://localhost:8282/item-type/api/v/1.0.0/save 400

Comment: Why is your frontend creating the GUID? Shouldn't it be done by Backend Storage?